# What is an ideal place for creating GCP Private Service Connect Endpoint, Publish Service etc. in case of "Shared VPC" setup?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vpc, vpc-endpoint

I understand GCP Private Service Connect (PSC) is an effective solution for enabling service-centric private network connectivity for GCP APIs and other hosted services within and across VPC projects/organizations/on-prem setup based on Producer/Consumer project model.

GCP documentation on Private Service Connect explains the purpose, PSC Endpoint and Publish Service configuration however I don't find relevant details on what should be an ideal location (or best practice) for creating and configuring PSC Endpoint, Publish Service when you have Shared VPC based network setup.

IMO, PSC Endpoint & Publish Service are network resources so the ideal place is to create in 'Host Project' of Shared VPC Network as a 'Host Project' is meant for centralized network management.

Also, having PSC Endpoint and Publish Service in 'Host Project' will help in sharing a single 'PSC endpoint' for all the 'Service Project' resources (which otherwise require multiple PSC endpoints per Service Project). However I would like to understand from you if you have come across and/or implemented such scenario.

Update: I tried a Shared VPC setup wherein PSC creation is allowed in Service-Project which means GCP doesn't restrict the creation of PSC in Service-Project.

Host Project: [image]

Service Project: [image]

Service Project PSC setup: [image]

Comment: I never tried. But by experience, my feeling is that only the host project can create a PSC, not the service project. You can have a try, but it could immediately answer your question!!

Comment: Hi @guillaumeblaquiere - I tried creating Shared VPC setup, however it allowed me to create PSC in a service project. Imaged attached above for reference.

Comment: Arf, my assumption was the bad one! Thanks for confirming!

Comment: Now to answer the best place, it's opinionated!  If you use a Google Cloud project per business/tech project, host the PSC in the service project that is the most relevant.